# removeAll method with different object types

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists on which I want to do bulk operations like using method removeAll, retainAll, contains. The problem is both the lists have different type of objects having one field which is same.  Its like

```
class ObjectType1{
  Long field1;
  String field2;
  String field3
 }

class ObjectType2{
Long field1;
String field4;
Long field5
```

}

So list1 contains elements of ObjectType1, and list2 contains ObjectType2. I want to do bulk operations based on field1 which is common in both object types.

I was thinking of implementing equals method in both the objects based on the common field. But then thought it may be wrong to make equals on just one field as in future there may be need to add comparison based on other fields in equals method. Please suggest.

Hope I have made my query clear enough. Please let me know for clarifications.

Comment: I guess you have to override equals method.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Google's Guava library. You can use [`Collections2.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to achieve this. Here's how you would do `retainAll()`, for example:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
...
List<ObjectType1> list1 = ...;
List<ObjectType2> list2 = ...;
Colection<Long> list1field1 = 
  Collections2.transform(list1, 
                         new Function<ObjectType1, Long>() {
                           public Long apply(ObjectType1 input) {
                             return (null == input) ? null : input.field1;
                           }
                         });
Collection<Long> list2field1 = 
  Collections2.transform(list2, ...);

// list1.retainAll(list2) based on field1 equivalence
list1field1.retainAll(list2field1); // this affects the underlying list, ie list1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will give list of common values

```
package rais;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<ObjectType1> list1 = new ArrayList<ObjectType1>();

        ObjectType1 type1Obj1 = new ObjectType1(10001l, "XXX", "YYYY");
        list1.add(type1Obj1);

        ObjectType1 type1Obj2 = new ObjectType1(10002l, "XXX", "YYYY");
        list1.add(type1Obj2);

        ObjectType1 type1Obj3 = new ObjectType1(10003l, "XXX", "YYYY");
        list1.add(type1Obj3);

        ObjectType1 type1Obj4 = new ObjectType1(10004l, "XXX", "YYYY");
        list1.add(type1Obj4);

        ObjectType1 type1Obj5 = new ObjectType1(10005l, "XXX", "YYYY");
        list1.add(type1Obj5);

        List<ObjectType2> list2 = new ArrayList<ObjectType2>();

        ObjectType2 type2Obj1 = new ObjectType2(10001l, "XXX", 2000l);
        list2.add(type2Obj1);

        ObjectType2 type2Obj2 = new ObjectType2(10002l, "XXX", 2001l);
        list2.add(type2Obj2);

        ObjectType2 type2Obj3 = new ObjectType2(50002l, "XXX", 2002l);
        list2.add(type2Obj3);

        ObjectType2 type2Obj4 = new ObjectType2(50003l, "XXX", 2003l);
        list2.add(type2Obj4);

        List<ObjectType1> list3 = retainAll(list1, list2);

        for (ObjectType1 objectType : list3) {
            System.out.println(objectType);
        }

    }

    public static List<ObjectType1> retainAll(List<ObjectType1> firstList,  List<ObjectType2> secondList) {

        List<ObjectType1> list3 = new ArrayList<ObjectType1>();

        for (ObjectType1 first : firstList) {
            for (ObjectType2 second : secondList) {
                if (first.getField1().equals(second.getField1())) {
                    list3.add(first);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        return list3;

    }

}
```

in above program below two object

```
ObjectType1 type1Obj1 = new ObjectType1(10001l, "XXX", "YYYY");
            list1.add(type1Obj1);

            ObjectType1 type1Obj2 = new ObjectType1(10002l, "XXX", "YYYY");
            list1.add(type1Obj2);
```

have common **field1**  in both the classes list3 will contain only two element of type1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want something like

```
    class SuperObject{
        Long field1;
        public SuperObject(){}
        public void setField1(Long f){
            field1 = f;
        }
        public Long getField1(){
            return field1;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof SuperObject)
        return field1.equals(((SuperObject) obj).getField1());
    else
        return false;
}
    }
    class ObjectType1 extends SuperObject{
        String field2;
        String field3;
        ...    
}

    class ObjectType2 extends SuperObject{
        String field4;
        Long field5;
        ...
    }
```

The the list should be something like

```
List<SuperObject> list = new ArrayList<SuperObject>();
    ObjectType1 obj1 = new ObjectType1();
    ObjectType2 obj2 = new ObjectType2();
    list.add(obj1);
    list.add(obj2);
```

Objects in the list now have the same equal method implementation, based on the `field1`, which is in the superclass

Answer (score 0):

I have written code using interface

```
public interface IMatchable {

    Object getMatchingField();
}
```

Then my ObjectType1 and ObjectType2 are implementing this interface along with overriding equals method as

```
public class ObjectType1 implements IMatchable {

@Override
public Object getMatchingField() {
    return field1;
}
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    IMatchable matchableObj = null;
    if (obj instanceof IMatchable) {
        matchableObj = (IMatchable) obj;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return matchableObj.getMatchingField().equals(this.getMatchingField()) ? true: false;
}
}
```

Similarly ObjectType2 with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dilum writes, you can use Google's Guava library.
In addition if you have lists only, you should use `Lists.transform` instead.
Furthermore if you use Java 8, then it will look like:

```
List<Long> list1field1 =
    Lists.transform(list1, input -> input == null ? null : input.field1);
```

Or you can do it manually:

```
// list1.removeAll(list2);
Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();
for (ObjectType2 o2 : list2) {
    set.add(o2.field1);
}
Iterator<ObjectType1> i = list1.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (set.contains(i.next().field1)) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```